# xsl:value of and apply template to inside element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, value-of

what can I do if I have this:

```
<e1>t1<e2>t2</e2></e1>
```

and I want to translate with XSLT in:

```
<c1>t1<c2>t2</c2></c1>
```

I've tried with:

```
<xsl:template match="e1">
  <c1>
     <xsl:value-of select=".">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:value-of>
  </c1>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="e2">
  <c2>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </c2>
</xsl:template>
```

But i receive a mistake as value-of should be empty.

Comment: One example does not make a rule. Is that *all* you will ever have: an `<e1>` parent and an `<e2>` child?

Comment: It seems you are using XSLT 1.0, because in 2.0 you would get a different error. If you are using XSLT 1.0 please SAY SO, it's very hard to answer XSLT questions when you don't know which version is being used.

Comment: I, thanks for the reply, I didn't know that there was a difference between using xslt 1.0 and 2.0, anyway I'm using 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xsl:value-of` must be empty, no doubt. But you don't need anything inside it. The stylesheet below is an identity transform with two exceptions, namely replacing the element names of `e1` and `e2`.

It is quite generic in the sense that it replaces `e1` and `e2` in any XML document and leaves all the rest untouched.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="e1">
      <c1>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </c1>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="e2">
      <c2>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </c2>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<c1>t1<c2>t2</c2></c1>
```

Comment: Note that the two exceptions cover everything in the given example - leaving the rule with nothing to process.

Comment: I know - the input XML might just be a stripped-down sample, i.e. there might be other content apart from `e1` and `e2`.